# Select distinct rows by first column and max of second

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, distinct

I have the following table:

```
Item           Prod        Company
1.00961.501    PR011798    ditto
1.00961.501    PR012042    ditto
1.00961.501    PR013442    Pika
1.00961.502    PR012043    ditto
1.00961.503    PR011959    ditto
1.00961.503    PR011669    Bulb
1.00961.507    PR014783    ditto
1.00961.507    PR012050    ditto
```

I would like to select all the table grouped by `Item` taking only the max `Prod`. Something like this:

```
Item           Prod        Company
1.00961.501    PR012042    ditto
1.00961.502    PR012043    ditto
1.00961.503    PR011959    ditto
1.00961.507    PR014783    ditto
```

I tried the following:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT Item, MAX(Prod)
FROM    DataBase
WHERE   Company = 'ditto'
```

but it gives me

`Column 'Item' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

If I remove the `MAX`clause it returns no errors, but `Item` repeats for each `Prod`.

Any Idea?

### EDIT

I forgot to add the `Where` clause to the question.
As I do that, and try to use `Group By` instead of `Distinct` I get the following error:

`Column 'Company' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: You need to add `GROUP BY Item` at the end of your query.

Comment: BTW, SELECT _DISTINCT_ is not needed, since the GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Comment: BTW2, _database_ is a very poor table name. Chose a name that makes sense.

Comment: DataBase is a random name I wrote here cos I didn't want to put the real database name :P I Edited my question with further material. Group By doesn't work.

Comment: Do you need only the results for Company = 'ditto', or you want the results in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be like this;

```
SELECT  Item, MAX(Prod),Company
FROM    DataBase
WHERE   Company = 'ditto'
GROUP BY Item,Company;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to partition the product and then select one from that partition. 

You should try this below query.

```
  select Item, Prod, Company from 
  (
    select *,
    (ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Item order by Prod DESC)) as Row from [table_name] 
    where Company = 'ditto'
  ) t where Row = 1
```